# Mongodb Charts connect to Mongo but doesn`t find all databases

Tags: mongodb, docker

I've brought up the mongodb-charts in my desktop and connected it to my mongodb database. When I connect to the database through mongodb-charts I see all of my databases there except the one named "admin" which is the one I need and where my data is. Why is this happening? I am using the same user to connect studio 3T to my mongodb that I use to connect mongodb-charts to mongodb. The picture below shows that I have the database "admin" in mongodb when I connect through studio 3T, but can't see it when connecting by mongodb-charts to mongodb...

[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB Charts currently excludes databases which are considered internal:

- `admin`: stores [user & role](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-users-and-roles/) information
- [`config`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/config-database/): stores sharded cluster and session metadata
- [`local`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/local-database/): stores local node data including the replication oplog

It is  generally not recommend to use any of these databases for your own application data, however the MongoDB server (as at 4.2) does not prevent you from doing so.

If you have chosen to store application data in the `admin` database you will have to copy it to a new database in order to visualise in MongoDB Charts.